# serializing structure which includes pointers

Tags: c++, cross-platform, undefined-behavior, c++98

### Description of the problem

I have to serialize the following structure and store it a different memory location (e.g. the flash). The solution has to work when the new memory location is read only:

```
------------
| Header   |
------------
| object 1 |
------------
| object 2 |
------------
| object n |
------------
```

The Header struct has pointers to the allocated objects like e.g.

```cpp
struct Header {
  int* object1;
};
```

I know a proper solution would be to store the offset instead of pointers, but I work on an existing code base, where this is only an option if there is no other way to achieve this. The example above is very simplistic. In the actual usage the object list is used by a custom mem pool implementation. It can include hundreds of nested structures which include pointers to each other (the order + amount varies greatly between users. It can be a couple of kilobytes to multiple megabytes of data). In the end the implementation has to be able to return a pointer + size, so an user can store the structure e.g. in the flash.

### Current Approach to solve the problem

To achieve this I store the original base pointer of the Header and subtract it from the new base pointer after copying the structure to the new memory location:

```cpp
struct Header {
  char* base_ptr;
  char* object1;
  

  char* get_object1(char* new_base_ptr) {
      ptrdiff_t offset = (ptrdiff_t)new_base_ptr - (ptrdiff_t)base_ptr;
      return (char*)object1 + offset;
  }
 
  char* get_object2(char* new_base_ptr) {
      ptrdiff_t offset = (ptrdiff_t)object1 - (ptrdiff_t)base_ptr;
      return new_base_ptr + offset;
  }
};

int main() {
    void* alloc = malloc(sizeof(Header) + sizeof(char));
    Header* header = new(alloc) Header;
    header->base_ptr = (char*)alloc;
    header->object1 = (char*)alloc + sizeof(Header);
    *header->object1 = 5;
    std::cout << (int)*header->get_object1((char*)alloc) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)*header->get_object2((char*)alloc) << std::endl;

    void* alloc2 = malloc(sizeof(Header) + sizeof(char));
    memcpy(alloc2, alloc, sizeof(Header) + sizeof(char));
    free(alloc);
    Header* header2 = (Header*)alloc2;
    std::cout << (int)*header2->get_object1((char*)alloc2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)*header2->get_object2((char*)alloc2) << std::endl;
}
```

I did see the following reasons for the implementations `get_object1` and `get_object2`:

#### get_object1:

+ offset can be calculated once and then reused

- subtracting pointers to two different arrays (one in the flash and one to the old memory location), which might be undefined behavior. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t:

> Only pointers to elements of the same array (including the pointer one past the end of the array) may be subtracted from each other.

- The offset is bigger than the array size, which might be undefined behavior according to §5.7 ¶5 of the C++11 spec:

> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

#### get_object3:

+ both offset and the final pointer are calculated within the boundary of the array. Therefore it should not have undefined behavior.

### Question

I prefer the implementation in `get_object1`, since I can  reuse the offset. However I assume, that this implementation has undefined behavior. Are there similar problems in the `get_object2` implementation that I did not account for? Is this guaranteed to work properly when the Header is no standard layout type? Is there a better alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: I guess you left all speechless :)

Comment: Why use pointers at all? If you allocate an object in a memory block at an arbitrary offset from the start of the block, store the offset, not the pointer.

Comment: This is getting more complicated [with each post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67413782/is-the-pointer-subtraction-in-this-use-case-undefined-behavior?noredirect=1#comment119157622_67413782). Why instead of asking "is this code undefined", why not ask "how to do it"? || `*header->object1 = 5;` may not be aligned to `int`.

Comment: Why use pointers at all? I know this would be the proper solution, but I work on an existing code base, where I can not change the whole implementation to use offsets instead.

Comment: "how to do it". True any different more proper way to achieve this would be welcome as well (added this to the question). `*header->object1 = 5; may not be aligned to int`. In the actual implementation we simply align everything to 64 bit right now. I updated the question to use char instead, so it is correctly aligned in this simple example.

Comment: Am I missing something, or are these requirements contradictory? "store it a different memory location" "the new memory location is read only". Are you talking about at build-time?

Comment: On the first run the application returns the serialized version, which a customer by some means stores in the flash storage. On subsequent runs we get a pointer to this serialized version. At this point it might be read only.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better alternative way to achieve this?

Don't bother with trying to work around `memcpy`. Write your own copy function.

```
Header * copyHeader(const Header * source, void * where) {
    Header * dest = new (where) Header;
    dest->object1 = new (where + sizeof(Header)) int(source->object1);
    return dest;
}
```

And/or a factory

```
Header * makeHeader(void * where) {
    Header * dest = new (where) Header;
    dest->object1 = new (where + sizeof(Header)) int;
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: In my specific use case this has two problems: 1) the object list can become very big, so a custom copy function which updates all the pointers would become very complex (probably more complex than rewriting the complete code base to use indexes) 2) the API should just return a pointer and size for the user to copy to some different memory location. It is unclear how the memory has to be written to the storage (this will likely be different depending on the hardware and operating system)

Comment: @maxbachmann "the API should just return a pointer and size for the user to copy to some different memory location." Why? You have pointers. Copying the pointers leaves them pointing to the wrong place.

Comment: Alternatively, why pointers at all? why not `struct Data { int value1; /* etc */ }`?

Comment: 1) pointers because that's how the structs are currently designed. As someone noted already the proper solution would be to convert all pointers to offsets and store those offsets. `get_object2` hacks the pointers into an index, which is a less invasive change. 2) `Alternatively, why pointers at all?` I added this to the question. These are nested structs (often with lists of structs my_struct** which grow while the structure is created). In the case of an integer they are stored in the way you suggested.