# Does the pointer arithmetic in this usage cause undefined behavior

Tags: c++, c, undefined-behavior

This is a follow up to the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67416686/serializing-structure-which-includes-pointers). I was under the assumption, that the pointer arithmetic I originally used would cause undefined behavior. However I was told by a colleague, that the usage is actually well defined. The following is a simplified example:

```cpp
typedef struct StructA {
    int a;
} StructA ;

typedef struct StructB {
    StructA a;
    StructA* b;
} StructB;

int main() {
    StructB* original = (StructB*)malloc(sizeof(StructB));
    original->a.a = 5;
    original->b = &original->a;

    StructB* copy = (StructB*)malloc(sizeof(StructB));
    memcpy(copy, original, sizeof(StructB));
    free(original);
    ptrdiff_t offset = (char*)copy - (char*)original;
    StructA* a = (StructA*)((char*)(copy->b) + offset);
    printf("%i\n", a->a);
    free(copy)
}
```

According to §5.7 ¶5 of the C++11 spec:

> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

I assumed, that the following part of the code:

```cpp
ptrdiff_t offset = (char*)copy - (char*)original;
StructA* a = (StructA*)((char*)(copy->b) + offset);
```

causes undefined behavior, since it:

1. subtracts two pointers, which point to different arrays
2. the resulting pointer of the offset calculation does not point into the same array anymore.

Does this cause undefined behavior, or do I misinterpret the C++ specification? Does the same apply in C as well?

### Edit:

Following the comments I assume the following modification would still be undefined behavior because of the object usage after the lifetime has ended:

```cpp
ptrdiff_t offset = (char*)(copy->b) - (char*)original;
StructA* a = (StructA*)((char*)copy + offset);
```

Would it be defined when working with indexes instead:

```cpp
typedef struct StructB {
    StructA a;
    ptrdiff_t b_offset;
} StructB;

int main() {
    StructB* original = (StructB*)malloc(sizeof(StructB));
    original->a.a = 5;
    original->b_offset = (char*)&(original->a) -  (char*)original

    StructB* copy = (StructB*)malloc(sizeof(StructB));
    memcpy(copy, original, sizeof(StructB));
    free(original);
    StructA* a = (StructA*)((char*)copy + copy->b_offset);
    printf("%i\n", a->a);
    free(copy);
}
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct, for the exact reasons you mentioned. And, Yes same for C.

Comment: Yes, it's Undefined Behavior

Comment: Also, there is no StructB object at the malloc'ed location. You need to create one using placement new.

Comment: @rustyx do you mean after freeing original?

Comment: @maxbachmann no, you allocated memory but didn't create the object

Comment: You also have undefined behavior for using a pointer to an object after the object's lifetime has ended.

Comment: Stop using that colleague and get a new one.

Comment: Ask your colleague if anything can ensure that both allocations are distant by a multiple of the size of your struct? Of course, there is no guaranty, this is why it is defined UB.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie is there any advantage of a struct object for a POD struct?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: That is not a good basis for reasoning here. Quite commonly, there is a guarantee that the allocations differ by a multiple of the size of the structure: The size of the structure is either eight bytes (two four-byte members) or 16 (the pointer is eight bytes with eight-byte alignment), and `malloc` returns addresses that are multiples of 16. To conclude the behavior is undefined, it is sufficient to observe `original` is invalid after the memory it points to is freed, and, also, the subtraction is not between pointers into the same array.

Comment: @maxbachmann pardon? an instance of struct is an object, instance of class is an object, array is an object, a single int is an object. A so called POD struct object is a trivial struct or class with standard layout (no virtuals, no no-static consts, no virtual inheritance, no members of base class)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I still do not understand the problem with the malloc allocation of this struct (which as far as I understand is a POD struct).

Comment: @EricPostpischil depends which platform and which malloc (some platforms define several, e,g some may have BSD\POSIX mallocs, defined in different headers). E.g. on SPARC platform pointer returned malloc is aligned by byte while structure is required to be aligned by its member size. Casting pointer doesn't change location and attempt to operate with struct fields will cause "bus error" as platform doesn't allow unaligned operations. This is also case with multiple embedded systems where malloc have no alignment guarantee. But C++ `new` has. There is a key difference between new and malloc.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: A `malloc` that returns an unaligned address is not a conforming C or C++ implementation. C 2018 7.22.3 (which C++ inherits) says “… The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement…” Further, my comment does not say Yunès assertion regarding the multiple structure size never works but rather it is not a good basis for reasoning—because it supports the conclusion only in restricted circumstances—when we already have complete coverage on solid principles.

Comment: @EricPostpischil well, that and few others requirements of C18\C++20 made  the majority of existing platforms non-conforming , and that wouldn't change for a while and on some never would be fully conforming to C++20 because of instruction set. It's automatically "kinda" works on x86 because x86 doesn't have alignment requirement unless on some SIMD functions, but it suffers pin performance if that happens. But also, provided there are 96bit, 128bit, 256 and 512 bit data types with strict alignment requirement, a malloc becomes hugely ineffective on AMD64\ARM, SPARC, etc.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: The fact I cited the C 2018 standard does not mean the requirement is new in C 2018. It is not; this text in the C 2018 standard did not make previously conforming implementations non-conforming because it is not new. Equivalent text exists in the C 1990 standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil this exactly why it is UB! There is no guarantee, it is not a matter of alignment. No allocator can ensure you that in between two allocations the space in between is compliant with the size of the allocation (it is just non-sens).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: No, this is not why the behavior is not defined. You asked, perhaps rhetorically, “if anything can ensure that both allocations are distant by a multiple of the size of your struct?” Contrary to your assertion “there is no such guaranty,” the answer is yes. For the structures in the question, the properties of common C implementations result in their sizes being 4 bytes (for `StructA`) and 8 or 16 (for `StructB`). On macOS, for example, `malloc` always returns 16-byte aligned memory, and therefore the distance between any two allocations is always a multiple of the sizes…

Comment: … This is the cause of my assertion that it is not a good basis for reasoning: There are circumstances in which this reasoning fails to give the correct conclusion. If distance between allocations were the only issue, then the behavior would in fact be defined given the relevant and common properties. In contrast, a good basis for reasoning is the C standard explicitly states the behavior of subtracting pointers to objects not part of the same array is not defined. It therefore provides an unconditional basis, superior to your conditional basis that fails in common C implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is undefined behavior because there are severe restrictions on what can be done with pointer arithmetic. The edits that you have made and that were suggested do nothing to fix this.

#### Undefined Behavior in Addition

```cpp
StructA* a = (StructA*)((char*)copy + offset);
```

First of all, this is undefined behavior due to the addition onto `copy`:

> When an expression J that has integral type is added to or subtracted from an expression P of pointer type, the result has the type of P.
>
> - (4.1) If P evaluates to a null pointer value and J evaluates to 0, the result is a null pointer value.
> - (4.2) Otherwise, if P points to an array element i of an array object x with n elements ([`[dcl.array]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array)), the expressions P + J and J + P (where J has the value j) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element i+j of x if 0 ≤ i + j ≤ n and the expression P - J points to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element i − j of x if 0 ≤ i − j ≤ n.
> - (4.3) **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

See https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4

In short, performing pointer arithmetic on non-arrays and non-null-pointers is always undefined behavior. Even if `copy` or its members were arrays, adding onto a pointer so that it becomes:

- two or more past the end of the array
- at least one before the first element

is also undefined behavior.

#### Undefined Behavior in Subtraction

```cpp
ptrdiff_t offset = (char*)original - (char*)(copy->b);
```

The subtraction of your two pointers is also undefined behavior:

> When two pointer expressions P and Q are subtracted, the type of the result is an implementation-defined signed integral type; [...]
>
> - (5.1) If P and Q both evaluate to null pointer values, the result is 0.
> - (5.2) Otherwise, if P and Q point to, respectively, array elements i and j of the same array object x, the expression P - Q has the value i − j.
> - (5.3) **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

See https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#5

So subtracting pointers from one another, when they are not both null or pointers to elements of the same array is undefined behavior.

#### Undefined Behavior in C

The C standard has similar restrictions:

> (8) [...] If the pointer operand points to an element of
> an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from
> the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original
> array elements equals the integer expression.

(The standard does not mention what happens for non-array pointer addition)

> (9) When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
> or one past the last element of the array object; [...]

See §6.5.6 Additive Operators in the [C11 standard (n1570)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

#### Using Data Member Pointers Instead

A clean and type-safe solution in C++ would be to use data member pointers.

```cpp
typedef struct StructB {
    StructA a;
    StructA StructB::*b_offset;
} StructB;

int main() {
    StructB* original = (StructB*) malloc(sizeof(StructB));
    original->a.a = 5;
    original->b_offset = &StructB::a;

    StructB* copy = (StructB*) malloc(sizeof(StructB));
    memcpy(copy, original, sizeof(StructB));
    free(original);
    printf("%i\n", (copy->*(copy->b_offset)).a);
    free(copy);
}
```

#### Notes

The standard citations are from a C++ draft. The C++11 which you have cited does not appear to have any looser restrictions on pointer arithmetic, it is just formatted differently. See [C++11 standard (n3337)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

Comment: As far as I understand you answer this means that even my last approach, which stores the offset would cause undefined behavior. Is there any way to implement this without copying the struct and updating all pointers?

Comment: @maxbachmann you can use data member pointers in C++ to avoid all pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

The Standard explicitly provides that in situations it characterizes as Undefined Behavior, implementations may behave "in a documented fashion characteristic of the environment".  According to the Rationale, the intention of such characterization was, among other things, to identify avenues of "conforming language extension"; the question of when implementations support such "popular extensions" was a Quality of Implementation issue best left to the marketplace.

Many implementations intended and/or configured for low-level programming on commonplace platforms extend the language by specifying that the following equivalences hold, for any pointers `p` and `q` of type `T*` and integer expression `i`:

- The bit patterns of `p`, `(uintptr_t)p`, and `(intptr_t)p` are identical.
- `p+i` is equivalent to `(T*)((uintptr_t)p + (uintptr_t)i * sizeof (T))`
- `p-i` is equivalent to `(T*)((uintptr_t)p - (uintptr_t)i * sizeof (T))`
- `p-q` is equivalent to `((uintptr_t)p - (uintptr_t)q) / sizeof (T)` in all cases where the division would have no remainder.
- `p>q` is equivalent to `(uintptr_t)p > (uintptr_t)q` and likewise for all other relational and comparison operators.

The Standard does not recognize any category of implementations that always uphold those equivalences, as distinct from those that do not, in part because they did not wish to portray as "inferior" implementations for unusual platforms where such upholding equivalence would be impractical.  Instead, it expected that such implementations would be upheld on implementations where that would make sense, and programmers would know when they were targeting such implementations.  Someone writing memory-management code for the 68000, or for small-model 8086 (where such equivalences would naturally hold) could write memory management code that would run interchangeably on other systems where those equivalences would hold, but someone writing memory-management code for large-model 8086 would need to design it explicitly for that platform because those equivalences do not hold (pointers are 32 bits, but individual objects are limited to 65520 bytes and most pointer operations only act upon the bottom 16 bits of a pointer).

Unfortunately, even on platforms where such equivalences would normally hold, some kinds of optimizations may yield corner-case behaviors that differ from those otherwise implied by those equivalences.  Commercial compilers generally uphold the Spirit of C principle "don't prevent the programmer from doing what needs to be done", and can be configured to uphold the equivalences even when most optimizations are enabled.  The gcc and clang C compilers, however, don't allow such control over semantics.  When all optimizations are disabled, they will uphold those equivalences on commonplace platforms, but there is no other optimization setting that will prevent them from making inferences that would be inconsistent with them.